# Zend framework how can i get value from view and controller when render() is used?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have this code in `layout/formsde/url.phtml`:

```
<?php
$use_url = $this->use_url;
foreach($this->match_de as $k=>$v) {
  if($this->serverUrl(true) == $k) {  
    $use_url = $v;  
  }
}
?>
```

I have 1000 pages with following line:

`<?=$this->render("layout/formsde/url");?>`

Now the problem is `$this->use_url` and `$this->match_de` is null its not getting the value from Controllers where it is assigned as below:

```
return new ViewModel(array(
    'description' => $this->de_desc,
    'use_url' => $this->layout()->use_url,
    'match_de' => $this->layout()->match_de,          
));
```

How can i pass the value to ->render() ? so that i have `$this->match_de` value with exact which is in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass array with values you need to the render

```
//Example
$this->render('layout/formsde/url', array(
       'use_url' => $this->use_url, 
       'match_de' => $this->match_de));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to define variables in the template which is rendered by the view renderer `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer`. You can pass an second argument as array.

```
<?=$this->render("layout/formsde/url", array(
    'description' => $this->de_desc,
    'use_url' => $this->layout()->use_url,
    'match_de' => $this->layout()->match_de,          
));?>
```

More information about PhpRenderer::render() method can be found in the [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.renderer.php-renderer.html).